# Giving error in chrome like cannot read properties of undefined in Angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome, web-component, angular-elements

Created two web components: web-comp-1, web-comp-2

When I tried to add in HTML page, I am getting console error like below

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
at new m.<computed> (web-comp-1.js:3:2706)
at new t (web-comp-1.js:3:12616)
```

When I checked the line, the code is,

`(o = (u = F && 1 === a.create.length) ? Reflect.construct`

Generated web component using below versions and angular elements:
"@angular/animations": "14.2.7",
"@angular/cdk": "14.2.5",
"@angular/common": "14.2.7",
"@angular/compiler": "14.2.7",
"@angular/core": "14.2.7",
"@angular/elements": "14.2.7",

Stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-bkqbag?file=index.html

If you run in stack blitz, you wont see any error, you need to download the project and open in only "Chrome". This issue happening only in chrome, not in mozilla

[image]

Comment: Please put the same in an web IDE like stackblitz so that can test it. also try to put the errors in text format ^^  [read here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) .

Comment: This error indicates that the property before **create** is undefind.

Comment: @AbolfazlAlmas added stackblitz link

Comment: I couldn't find where the problem is. look [here](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/issues/335) Maybe the reason for your project's error is the use of deprecated package.

Comment: @AbolfazlAlmas

We have document register element at below locations in angular.json: "projects.myWidgetBuilder.architect.build.options.scripts" and "projects.elements.architect.build.options.scripts"

"scripts": [ { "input": "node_modules/document-register-element/build/document-register-element.js" }

Do I need to remove these above lines from myWidgetBuilder and elements in angular.json?

Comment: Probably your problem is the same as that person. Try it, if there is no new problem after removing that import, so remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two solutions:**

**a)** Upgraded document-register-element package from 1.7.2 to 1.14.10 in package json, the error gone away. Thank you @Abolfazl Almas, your link triggered me an idea

OR

**b)** Remove document-register-element package (deprecated) and add "@ungap/custom-elements" and change in angular.json file like below, wherever you see document-register-element file path:

```
"scripts": [{
            "input": "node_modules/@ungap/custom-elements/index.js"
 ]}
```